# Question regarding the acceptance of Early Fasting and Eid Celebration with Varying Moon Sighting

Tags: halal-haram, sawm, muslim-practices, eid

I do not want to bring the moon sighting controversy here; I just want to know if, in my country, one city follows the Saudi moon sighting, will their fasting be accepted even if the moon isn’t sighted elsewhere in the country, and all the rest of the people will start fasting from the day the moon is officially sighted?

I mean, since they are fasting before sighting the moon and will celebrate Eid when one day of fasting is still left, does it not mean they are effectively skipping one day of fasting? Or, in general, will their fasting and celebration of Eid be accepted?